# Why does my function won't wait for api response before return?

Tags: node.js, function, axios

i'm trying to make weather api function because i don't wanna swim in spagetti code but i couldn't return my api response properly.

That's my weather-api.js ;

```
export default () => {
  
  var link = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=istanbul&lang=tr&units=metric&APPID=9e0e8bbf1392be5b8b8ae9d453645ff8"

  axios.get(link).then(
      (response) => {
          var result = response.data;
          //console.log(result);
          return result;
          
      },
      (error) => {
          console.log(error);
      }
  );

}
```

and the code in which I call the function

```
import weather from "./weather-api.js";

let data = await weather();


console.log(data)
```

How can i make function to wait api response before returning ?

Comment: Make which function wait before returning?  In general, you don't/can't do that in Javascript.,  Asynchronous functions return BEFORE you have your result.  When using promises, they return a promise and the caller uses that promise to get the eventual resolved result.

Answer (score -1):

You can use asynchronous. Define your function as async and await for api response. That will fix your problem.

Example code,

```
async apiRequest(){
   const response = await axios('/data');
   return await res.json();
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: The code is not your solution. I used it to demonstrate async in js.